# Move one column to another table & update that column by foreign ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a big table and I need to modify the structure.

Here is the table structure.

Table Name : "Articles"

```
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
| id(int) | details(text) | category(varchar) | tag(varchar) |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

**Important points:**

- There are around 250k (250,000) rows in this table
- There are around 10k unique categories

**What I need to change**

I created table called "category" and then make the category column as a foreign key for that table.

**This is what I expect:**

I need to move category names to category table and then need to update articles table with category ID.

Table Name : "Articles"

```
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
| id(int) | details(text) | category(int)     | tag(varchar) |
+---------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Table Name : "Category"

```
+---------+-------------------+
| id(int) | category(varchar) |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Is it possible to do just using MySQL? (I know that how to do that using some PHP scripts and MySQL commands). But I asked it here because if I can do it with just MySQL I can save lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that `category(id)` column is automatically filled (it is auto_increment column):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

INSERT INTO Category( category )
SELECT DISTINCT category(varchar)
FROM Articles;

UPDATE Articles a, Category c
SET a.category(int) = c.id
WHERE a.category(varchar) = c.category
;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I use `category(varchar)` and `category(int)` to distinguish one (int) `category` column from the other (varchar) `category` in the same table. This is of course syntactically incorrect, you must use proper and distinct column names instead of `category(xxx)`

Comment: Thank you so much. You save around 1-2 hour time of me. Again thanks.